# Oracle Connection Expires and doesn't open

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, amazon-web-services

This is a bit strange. I have two Oracle databases. One is local. Other is from Amazon. What happens is very weird. I'm using C# to this.

- If I open a connection and do some query, it works.
- If after 1+ hour I open a connection, It denies it in the first time, then allows it.

When after 1+ hour that I executed the last query in Amazon database, it throws a new `OracleException` and it just happens in Amazon database. In my local database it leaves me to open a connection anytime, but there it denies it on first time and allows on the second. Also if I use `try{} catch() {}` it doesn't allows. My current code:

```
private OracleConnection _oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Oracle"].ConnectionString);

private void OpenConnection()
{
    if (_oracleConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    _oracleConnection.Open();
}

public void MyAction(employer)
{
    OpenConnection();
    using (OracleCommand command = _oracleConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "proc_0001";
        command.Parameters.Clear();
        command.Parameters.Add("pi_employer_id, OracleDbType.Int32").Value = employer;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

The weird is that if I just execute it in a short time, it goes OK, but if I stay more than 1 hour without to tick Oracle, it throws me an Exception in `OpenConnection()` and as I'm calling this method in an event of a button click, when I do it again, after the exception, I get my result. I'm starting to think that Oracle is just joking with me. I saw Oracle Documentation and C# Documentation and `Connection LifeTime/Connection TimeOut` in Oracle's string, but they are to KEEP a connection and I get the error when OPENING a connection, bu as I said, only after a big time and it works fine on second. I don't want to use a workaround to it. Do you know what is the cause of this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the OracleException?

Comment: Unable to perform my query after "Open a connection" in my first try. On second it goes. I can't say exactly because I must wait 1 hour for each test, but it throws me that "Can't perform". :( Oracle is being bad with me.

Comment: Well you should probably log the error including the ORA number. Also you might consider using connection pooling e.g. `Pooling=true;Min Pool Size=0; Max Pool Size=100;` instead of managing it yourself.

Comment: You should not keep the connection open. The connection should be closed after you made your call which will release the connection to the ADO pool for reuse. When an OracleConnection object is requested, it is obtained from the pool if a usable connection is available. The connection pooler periodically scans connection pools looking for objects that have been released to the pool and are marked as invalid (connection failed).